# CURSOR with Update Column Name Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

This is my first post on any forum asking for help with SQL. I have always found the answer I need by searching (usually on this site).

I have a cursor with a variable column name and a where clause that includes the column name.

Can anybody tell me why it says many rows were updated but my data never changes? #WHold is a temp table that holds the column names I need to loop through. It also relates to the row data value. I could use a pivot table but I am curious why this cursor is not working.

If I run an update statement the rows are updated.

---My Update statement---

```
UPDATE MT
SET MT.[10004] = MTD.WHoldAmt
FROM dbo.MyData MT 
        INNER JOIN dbo.MyDataDetail MTD
        ON MT.EEID = MTD.EEID AND MTD.WHold = '10004'
```

---My CURSOR---

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @getColumnName CURSOR
DECLARE @MTColumnName VARCHAR(100)

SET @getColumnName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT WHold,'MT.['+WHold+']' FROM #Whold

OPEN @getColumnName
FETCH NEXT FROM @getColumnName INTO @ColumnName,@MTColumnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    UPDATE MT
    SET @MTColumnName = MTD.WHoldAmt
    FROM dbo.MyData MT 
    INNER JOIN dbo.MyDataDetail MTD ON MT.EEID = MTD.EEID AND MTD.WHold = @ColumnName
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getColumnName INTO @ColumnName,@MTColumnName

END
CLOSE @getColumnName
DEALLOCATE @getColumnName
```

---Results from cursor though none of the data was changed in the table MyData---

(531 row(s) affected)

(8 row(s) affected)

(2757 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(14 row(s) affected)

(461 row(s) affected)

(511 row(s) affected)

(17 row(s) affected)

(9 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL is updating the value of @MTColumnName, try to change your query to:

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @getColumnName CURSOR 
DECLARE @SQLUpdate VARCHAR(max)  -- Variable to hold SQL Command
SET @getColumnName = CURSOR FOR
SELECT WHold  FROM #Whold 

OPEN @getColumnName
FETCH NEXT FROM @getColumnName INTO @ColumnName,@MTColumnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    SET @SQLUpdate = 'UPDATE MT SET MT.[' + @ColumnName + '] = MTD.WHoldAmt
    FROM dbo.MyData MT INNER JOIN dbo.MyDataDetail MTD ON MT.EEID = MTD.EEID AND MTD.WHold = ''' + @ColumnName + ''''

    exec @SQLUpdate

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getColumnName INTO @ColumnName,@MTColumnName

END
CLOSE @getColumnName
DEALLOCATE @getColumnName
```